# How can I overlay two images in HTML5

Tags: html, image

How can I put my logo on top of another image in HTML5 and/or CSS3

I did this on photoshop for a friend

https://i.stack.imgur.com/46DUc.png

there are 2 images, I have no idea how can I put thos on top of each other!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the two images in an absolute position and then position them with top,left,right,bottom..

your html

```
<div id="image1"> <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcThtVuIQ7CBYssbdwtzZjVLI_uw09SeLmyrxaRQEngnQAked5ZB"></div>

<div id="image2"> <img src="http://www.desktop-bilder.com/images/wallpapers/40-wiese-und-himmel.jpg"> </div>
```

your css

```
#image1 {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
}

#image2 img {
width: 80%;
}
```

EDIT: CHECK OUT THIS [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ5Mj/1/)

Comment: I can't I just created this account

Answer (score 1):

one approach is to set one as background-image and other as an regular image ... 
**Working Example :** http://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/fDuu5/7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body 
{
background-image:url('http://wallike.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/flower-desktop-background-640x400.jpg');
background-color:#cccccc;
background-size:320px 280px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<img src="http://www.southeastern.edu/admin/stu_dev/family_day/images/selulogo.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! but the other thing my background is repeating, i tried to add the norepeat in css but it didn't work :( the background just disappeared

Comment: add background-repeat:no-repeat; on last line of css after color attr.

Comment: One thing, I'm a totally newbie in css, can you tell me how can I resize the <img> logo? and moving it a bit on the left

Comment: <style>
#myimage {
left:100px;
}
</style>
<img src="source" width="100px" height="100px" id="myimage" >

Comment: there are several ways to do this. Which one is the best depends on what you're trynna do . You can learn about html and css positioning at w3schools.com. They have nice and easy tutorials for newbies