# Overlap two images in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, image, overlap

im trying to overlap to images. One of them is hidden and its show after picking in the right image in the "clipart library" section. And the other image i get is uploading it from your browser.

I have used posiotion:absolute before to overlap two images, but it doesnt work for me in this caes.

```
<div id="bgcolor">
    <img id="thumbnil" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;" src="" alt="" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img id="tiger" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/202300/Blue-surprised-cartoon-smiley.png" height="50" width="50" style="position:absolute;">
</div>
```

Here is the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xq239ko9/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I overlay two images in HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276107/how-can-i-overlay-two-images-in-html5)

Answer (score 0):

Make the containing `div` have a style `position:relative;`. Then make the images `position:absolute; top:0; left: 0;`. This makes both images appear on the same position within the parent `div`. Please note, that the parent `div` will lose it's size, as the images will be positioned outside the document flow.

Another remark: 
- Try to use one style attribute per tag.
- Try to hide images by using `display:none;` instead of an empty `src` attribute
- Try to use the `width` and `height` style properties instead of tag attributes

Comment: the problem when doind this is that the image that I upload get outside the div when its bigger than intended. Any tip to fix this?